# Binding on nested user control is not working in Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I have a usercontrol(X) that gets loaded in the shell, I am using Screen/Conductors. Control X has a tabcontrol that I am trying to load with another usercontrol(Y) as a TabItem. Both the controls have their on ViewModels that do not share anything yet.

Usercontrol X:

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class CategoryViewModel : Screen, IShell
{}
```

Xaml in Control X:

```
<TabItem Header="Award Images">
    <StackPanel>
        <Views:ImageView cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}" />
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
```

Usercontrol Y:

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class ImageViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShell
{}
```

When I run the application I get the CategoryView loaded in the shell and working fine. ImageView gets loaded but none of the functionality is available.

I am expecting to see some dummy data that I am putting in the ListView on ImageView through the constructor of ImageViewModel.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE: 
CategoryView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Name="CategoryViewUserControl" 
         x:Class="Central.BusinessObjects.Wpf.Views.CategoryView" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended" 
         xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro" 
         xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Central.BusinessObjects.Wpf.Views" 
         xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:Central.BusinessObjects.Wpf.Converters" MinHeight="500" MinWidth="500">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>            
        <Converters:CategoryTypeConverter x:Key="CategoryTypeConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ToolBar>
        <Button Height="23" Width="75" cal:Message.Attach="SaveCategories($dataContext)">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image />
                <TextBlock Text="Save" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>           
    </ToolBar>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ComboBox x:Name="Types" 
                  IsEditable="True" 
                  Background="Beige" 
                  IsReadOnly="True" 
                  Text="Select Award Type" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Description"                     
                  Height="23" Width="219" />

        <ComboBox x:Name="Awards" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Year" 
                  Background="Beige"                      
                  Height="23" Width="120" />
        <Label Content="Image" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="AwardImage" TextAlignment="Justify" MinWidth="300" Background="Beige" />
        <Button x:Name="BrowseAwardImage" Content="Browse" />
    </StackPanel>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Award Categories">
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="Description" Background="Beige" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />

                    <Label Content="Reveal Time" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />

                    <extToolkit:TimePicker Background="Beige" 
                                           Value="{Binding Path=RevealTime}" 
                                           Format="ShortTime" 
                                           ShowButtonSpinner="False" 
                                           Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" 
                                           AllowSpin="False" />

                    <ComboBox x:Name="CategoryTypes" 
                              Background="Beige" 
                              Height="23" Width="120"
                              Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" />

                    <Button Content="Add" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="0" 
                            cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Add($dataContext)]" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,10">
                        <DataGrid  x:Name="Categories" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category Name" MinWidth="500">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Path=Description}" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="(" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Descriptor, Converter={StaticResource CategoryTypeConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                                <TextBlock Text=")" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reveal Time" Binding="{Binding Path=RevealTime}" />
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Nominees">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Content="Edit" 
                                                    cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action AddNominees(CategoryViewUserControl)]" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Award Images">
            <StackPanel>
                <Views:ImageView cal:Bind.Model="{Binding Path=Central.BusinessObjects.Wpf.ViewModels.ImageViewModel}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

ImageView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Central.BusinessObjects.Wpf.Views.ImageView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="LabelName" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button x:Name="AddImages" Content="Add" Width="40" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <ListView x:Name="SelectedImages" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" />
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Caption}" />
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The two view models are completely independent at the moment.

Comment: What is the TabControl ItemsSource bound to?

Comment: TabControl is bound to a ObservableCollection<Categories> Categories defined in CategoryViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure without seeing more code, but I think the issue is that your `TabControl`'s `ItemsSource` is bound to a collection of a `Category` type, so in your binding expression, Caliburn.Micro will attempt to bind each property on your `Category` type to a control on the `ImageView`.

Are you trying to have one category per tab? Where each tab displays something slightly differently? Either way, you probably should be binding your tab control to a collection of view models, rather than a collection of a `Category` type. Altenatively, perhaps a `DataTemplateSelector` to display the appropriate view based on the `Category` type.

**Update**

You would be better off having the `ImageViewModel` as a property of your `CategoryViewModel`. Instantiate the `ImageViewModel` in the `CategoryViewModel` (assigning it to the property), and then change your binding expression from:

```
<Views:ImageView cal:Bind.Model="{Binding Path=Central.BusinessObjects.Wpf.ViewModels.ImageViewModel}" />
```

to:

```
<Views:ImageView cal:Bind.Model="{Binding MyImageViewModelProperty}" />
```

The following may also work:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyImageViewModelProperty" />
```

Comment: "TabControl is bound to a ObservableCollection<Categories> Categories defined in CategoryViewModel."

Comment: Could you add the full code for CategoryViewModel/CategoryView, ImageViewModel/ImageView

Comment: Added the view...not sure if view model is still needed as the current functionality of ImageView is completely independent on Categoryview.